# Авторская пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли в переписке по интернету использовать авторские знаки препинания, вернее, те, которые стоят не по правилам?

Answer (score 6):

**Понятие об авторской пунктуации можно посмотреть у Розенталя**

[Авторская пунктуация | Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=197)

В целом авторская пунктуация — **это не произвольная постановка знаков препинания по собственному желанию, а нечто более ответственное и сложное, чем пунктуация классическая.** Это сознательное отступление от правил, которые вы знаете, но которые не могут должным образом выразить содержание вашего текста.

К примеру, если вы не закроете причастный оборот в середине предложения или не поставите запятую перед союзом И в сложном предложении (при отсутствии общего элемента), то это  будет **обычной ошибкой, а не авторской пунктуацией.**

**Реально авторское решение часто встречается  в некоторых темах**, например, при обособлении обстоятельственных оборотов или вводных слов, когда сама структура предложения предполагает наличие двух решений. Но и здесь вы должны хорошо знать правила, чтобы сослаться на свое авторское решение.

Часто в качестве авторского знака используется **интонационное тире,** которое соответствует паузе в устной речи и позволяет оформить текст более эмоционально  и экспрессивно.

Конечно, записи в Сети — это не диктант в школе и не сочинение на выпускном экзамене, здесь требования менее строгие. **Главное — не делать грубых ошибок, которые легко заметят окружающие.** Очень плохо, к примеру,  смотрятся "лишние запятые", которые сразу вызовут сомнения по поводу вашей грамотности. А вот ломать голову над выбором тире, двоеточия, запятой в бессоюзном предложении не стоит, лучше обойтись универсальной запятой, так как вряд ли кто-нибудь будет проверять направленность причинно-следственной связи. **Поэтому не забывайте о главных правилах — и пишите свободно, иначе речь будет скованной и неинтересной.**

**И ещё о "свободной" (но не авторской) пунктуации.** Посмотрите ответы на форуме, и вы убедитесь, что **пунктуация бывает "разная".**  Вот строго обсуждается  заданное предложение из художественного текста: грамматика, правила, ссылки на источники. **Но текст ответа достаточно свободный, это книжно-разговорная речь:** соблюдаются  основные правила, а конкретные знаки (запятая, тире, двоеточие) выбираются скорее интуитивно. И еще более свободной является грамматика и пунктуация  в комментариях, это, как правило, запись разговорной речи.

Comment: Значит, при причине, и изъяснении вместо двоеточия можно поставить запятую?

Comment: А в таких случаях - условие-следствие, резкое противопоставление, причина - следствие, запятая употребляется вместо тире.

Answer (score 1):

Хозяин барин. Если вы их поставите не по правилам, то они и будут стоять не по правилам. Можно – в том смысле, что в тюрьму за это не посадят и даже штрафа не возьмут. Или вы имели в виду что-то другое? Что такое "можно"?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но не нужно. "Авторская" - она у авторов, у интернет-писунов это обычно воспринимается просто как банальная безграмотность тиновская.
А в остальном - лучше, чем Sibylla, и не сказать

```
Только Они, умудряются Писать, Вот Так
```