# Нужна ли запятая для выделения конкретного слова?

Tags: пунктуация

> Не все улетают на юг зимой.

Имеется в виду, что не все улетают на юг именно зимой.
Нужен ли какой-либо знак пунктуации перед "зимой"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном предложении нет необходимости использовать запятую перед словом "зима". Однако, если есть авторский замысел, то запятую можно ставить там, где автор сочтет нужным.

Об авторской пунктуации: см., напр., [Авторская пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430653/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_4_punct/.

Comment: Очень хотелось бы знать, в каком именно месте в этом предложении (по Вашим словам — _где автор сочтет нужным_)  можно поставить авторскую запятую?

Comment: Не я автор этого предложения, поэтому не могу говорить за него. Лучше спросить у автора, который даже тему создал, чтобы узнать, можно ли ставить запятую в этом предложении. А то, что автор может ее поставить, думаю, в комментариях не нуждается.

Comment: Не-не, нуждается! Автор вопроса только **предполагает.** А вы-то утверждаете, что _запятую можно ставить там, где автор сочтет нужным_. Так вот мне и интересно: если не в этом месте, то — где?

Answer (score 0):

Если бы это предложение было составлено мною и если бы я сильно уж хотел обособить наречие "зимой", то я бы его присоединительным членом сделал — посредством парцелляции:

> Не все улетают на юг. Зимой.

Может быть, зима - это что-то важное для тех, кто летает.

А если не придумывать всяких фантазий, то обособлять его не нужно.